# Obfuscate privacy-sensitive headers of mutt

Tags: email, mutt, headers

When I send a message using `mutt`, for instance:

```
echo "test body" | mutt -s "test subject" test@test.com
```

The email contains some headers like:

```
Message-ID: <AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFF@machine-id>
User-Agent: Mutt/X.Y.Z (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Although this is probably nitpicking, this is privacy sensitive information: the receiver does not have to know the name of my machine(s) neither which user-agent I'm using. Is there a way to either disable adding these headers, or if that is not possible obfuscate them?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mutt documentation (manual.txt) it should be possible to set a variable "hidden_host" to "yes" in the muttrc configuration file:

> ... When set, mutt will skip the host name part of $hostname variable
>   when adding the domain part to addresses ...

The version info. in the User-Agent can be suppressed in a similar way, by setting the User-Agent header string via "my_hdr". E.g. I do the following:

```
send-hook . my_hdr User-Agent: Mutt
```